# yesod add-handler results in error

Tags: haskell, web, yesod

I followed the 6 steps outlined here http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart (except the first step, b/c I already had stack), and everything works. However, when I attempt to run `stack exec -- yesod add-handler`, I get the following output:

```
Name of route (without trailing R): A
Enter route pattern (ex: /entry/#EntryId): /a
Enter space-separated list of methods (ex: GET POST): GET
yesod: Application.hs: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

I also tried it with the `yesod-postgres` stack template, and got the same result. Any ideas?

EDIT: Looks like this was already an issue https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1413.

Comment: Are you using `stack`? If so, did you run `stack setup`? I sometimes forget to run this and it results in a similar error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the issue, add-handler is broken in the scaffolding update.

However, you can add routes yourself. Let us say you want to add a route for GET requests at /NewRoute and name the resource NewRouteR

- On a new line add the new route in the `config/routes` file

  ```
  /NewRoute NewRouteR GET
  ```
- Create a new file in Handler directory - NewRoute.hs with this default content

  ```
  module NewRoute where
  import Import

  getNewRoute :: Handler Html
  getNewRoute = error "Route not implemented : NewRoute"
  ```
- Add this to list of imports in `Application.hs`

  ```
  import Handler.NewRoute
  ```
- Also add it to the list of exposed modules in the .cabal file

  ```
  exposed-modules:
      Handler.NewRoute
  ```
- also depending on whether you need the authentication provided by the scaffolding, add this route to the list of patterns in the `Yesod App` instance in `Foundation.hs`

  ```
  isAuthorized NewRouteR _ = return Authorized -- No authentication
  -- or --
  isAuthorized NewRouteR _ = isAuthenticated
  ```